# Side by Side BarPlot

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, seaborn

I'm trying to create this kind of "side by side" barplot with `seaborn` and `pandas`.

[image]

this is how I create data frame:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data={'investors': ['first','second','third'], 'stocks': [23, 123, 54], 'bonds': [54, 67, 123], 'real estate': [45, 243, 23]})
```

And here is barplot code:

```
sns.factorplot(x='investors', y='bonds', data=dfs, kind='bar')
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: have you taken a look at this tutorial? https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.14-visualization-with-seaborn.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) on your dateframe then plot it with seaborn.

*update: factorplot was changed to catplot in newer versions of seaborn.*

```
sns.catplot(x = 'investors', y='value', 
            hue = 'investments',data=dfs1, 
            kind='bar')
```

---

```
# import libraries
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.DataFrame(data={'investors': ['first','second','third'], 
                         'stocks': [23, 123, 54], 
                         'bonds': [54, 67, 123], 
                         'real estate': [45, 243, 23]})

dfs1 = pd.melt(dfs, id_vars = "investors")
dfs1 = dfs1.rename(columns={"variable": "investments"})

print(dfs1)

    investors    investments    value
0   first         stocks         23
1   second        stocks        123
2   third         stocks         54
3   first          bonds         54
4   second         bonds         67
5   third          bonds        123
6   first      real estate       45
7   second     real estate      243
8   third      real estate       23


sns.factorplot(x = 'investors', y='value', 
               hue = 'investments',data=dfs1, kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

##### output :-

[image: barplot]

Comment: where does the column heading "investments" come from?

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski I have renamed the column "variable" after the `pd.melt` to "investments" and I had forgot to include it in the answer. I have added the rename step in the answer now. Thank you for noticing and letting me know. Sorry for the late response, I haven't used SO in a while.