# How to summarise data to make a grouped bar chart in Altair / Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, altair

In R I would code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df<-data.frame(mydate=rep(as.Date("2022-01-01")+0:90, each=10),
               mygroup=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size=910, replace=T))
df %>% 
  mutate(mymonth=round_date(mydate, "month")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mymonth, fill=mygroup))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

I am learning Python\Pandas\Altair\Streamlit, and want to make a Streamlit dashboard with a similar chart to the above. I suspect there is a more efficient way to make produce this chart. Here is my current best effort:

```
import streamlit as st #version 1.14.0
import pandas as pd    #version 1.5.1
import altair as alt   #version 4.2.0

df=pd.DataFrame({'mydate':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='4/09/2020').repeat(10),
                 'mygroup':pd.Series(["A", "B", "C"]).sample(n=1000, replace=True)})

c = alt.Chart(df).transform_window(
  sort=[{'field': 'yearmonth(mydate)'}],
  cumulative_count='count(*)', # incorrect count
).mark_bar().encode(
  x='yearmonth(mydate):O',
  y='cumulative_count:Q',
  #xOffset='mygroup:N', #error
  color='mygroup'
)
st.altair_chart(c, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

The chart is currently a stacked bar chart, and I would like to make a grouped bar.

I found `xOffset` property via https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092979/10276092 - However I get the message *SchemaValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed ('xOffset' was unexpected)*

The bars themselves look like they have horizontal banding. I suspect this is because I am not summarizing (in the `transform_window`?) before displaying.

As I am post this, I notice the calculated variable cumulative_count is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was multi-step. First, using `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-15')` to bring all the dates together per month (I choose the 15th, because the 1st was rounding down into the previous month. Bug?).

Then `groupby` and `count` to summarize the data. `.reset_index` created a nice dataframe, and `rename(columns=` named the summary count field properly.

Within the chart, set the width and height of the chart, and the `size` (previously `barsize`) of the bars. the `facet=` parameter makes the stacked barchart into a grouped barchart. Finally the `configure_header` cleans the labiling.

```
import streamlit as st #version 1.14.0
import pandas as pd    #version 1.5.1
import altair as alt   #version 4.2.0

df=pd.DataFrame({'mydate':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='4/09/2020').repeat(10),
  'mygroup':pd.Series(["A", "B", "C"]).sample(n=1000, replace=True)})

df['mydate2'] = df['mydate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-15')
df2 = df.groupby(by=['mydate2', 'mygroup']).count().reset_index().rename(columns={'mydate': 'counts'})

c = alt.Chart(df2, width=75, height=200).mark_bar(size=20).encode(
  x='mygroup:N',
  y='counts:Q',
  facet='month(mydate2):O',
  color='mygroup:N'
).configure_header(labelOrient='bottom',
                    labelPadding = 3).configure_facet(spacing=5
 )
st.altair_chart(c) #, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58739328/10276092