# Python - Issues with bar charts

Tags: python, pandas

everyone!

I don't have the dataset with me so I'll make a mock code to simulate what I'm trying to do. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Kevin', 'Jack'],
        'Sales Q1':[2024, 2421, 2219, 2018],
        'Sales Q2':[2822, 2144, 1992, 2558]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

I haven't really been able to search good ways to solve this but I'm trying to have it so the results look like...

[image]

I could create bar charts through SNS but it ultimately can't hue between the Name bracket. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028043/side-by-side-barplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Side by Side BarPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028043/side-by-side-barplot)

Comment: It's not. In that one, there are two categorical values. Here, there is only one and I'm trying to put the numbers side by side and not the categories.

Comment: the same idea applies, see @Nk03 answer below,  I think this shoud be flagged as duplicate nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df1 = df.melt(id_vars='Name')
sns.barplot(x='Name', y='value', hue='variable', data=df1)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

#### [image]OUTPUT

Comment: So that looks great but the thing is that your answer has value in your df as all in one column. I have two columns with values and I want those to be next to each other.

Comment: @ESarousi Here `Q1/Q2` values are separate `Q1` is in blue while `Q2` is in orange and they're next to each other. Can you try the solution once? Not getting what i missed.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it certainly appears from what I see that both values are within a single column "variable".

In my example, I don't know which column would be the hue and which would be the y.